# The instant type changes to int in Foreign Key in Django

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py in django

```
class Site(models.Model):
    # Site ID
    siteID = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ".format(self.siteID,)

class EndDevice(models.Model):
    edevID = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    siteID = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deviceCategory = models.BigIntegerField()
```

And this is the method to post in views.py:

```
class RegisterSite(generics.ListAPIView):
    '''
    GET site/
    POST site/
    '''
    queryset = Site.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    # POST Regisger Site
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        a_site = Site.objects.create(
            siteID=request.data["siteID"],
#            edevID=request.data["edevID"]
        )
        return Response(
            data=DataSerializer(a_site).data,
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
class RegisterDevice(generics.ListAPIView):
    '''
    GET device/
    POST device/
    '''
    queryset = EndDevice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        siteID, created = Site.objects.get_or_create(
        siteID=request.data["siteID"],
    )
        a_site = EndDevice.objects.create(
            edevID=request.data["edevID"],
            siteID = siteID,
            deviceCategory=request.data["deviceCategory"],
        )
        return Response(
            data=DeviceSerializer(a_site).data,
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
```

So what I am trying t do here is use the siteID from class Site for class EndDevice. But when I enter/ chose the value of siteID in Enddevice it changes to integer value. I checked the data base and it shows me int as its (siteID in EndDevice) characteristics. I was wondering how could I get the real value of siteID instead of an integer value.And I can accept character values while posting for class Site.

If the question is vague or unclear, please update me.
Thanks

**EDIT**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RveWL.png)

The serializer looks like:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ("siteID",)

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EndDevice
        fields = ("edevID", "siteID", "deviceCategory")
```

Comment: Can you please add a simple proof of the fact that it is indeed a int?

Comment: I have added the pic in edit.

Comment: Django will resolve this automatically, see type(a_site.siteID).

Comment: It shows this on running type: <class 'registration.models.Site'>. But when I input the data it shows me as a number. Any recommendations?

Comment: Could it be because of the serializer?

Comment: @Shubhankar as I said in my answer you have a confusion that `siteID` in `Site` model is maintaining the relationship between the two models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:**

> when I enter/ chose the value of siteID in Enddevice it changes to integer value

Well the reason why it gets converted to `int` is because you haven't specified your own primary key field so Django uses its default primary key as `Id` field which is an integer field.

**A:**

Inside of `Site` model change this:

```
siteID = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, unique = True)
```

to this:

```
siteID = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key = True)
```

Now what that does is that it sets `siteID` as your `primary_key` instead of django's default `Id`.

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#primary-key)